# Validating Integer using JSR303

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I decided to use JSR303 to validate my forms in Spring 3.0 MVC application. When I try to check `@NotEmpty` on `Integer` variable I have exception:

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found
>   for type: java.lang.Integer

First this variable was declared as `int` (protected int `partCount`) but I found on the Spring forum that primitives may cause some problems, so I've changed that to Integer. Still same exception. Any ideas?

PS. Same situation with `Double` and `Timestamp`, no problems with Strings

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what implementation you're using but here is what Hibernate Validator writes about the [`NotEmpty`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/NotEmpty.html) annotation (which is not part of the Bean Validation specification):

> Check that a String is not empty (not null and length > 0) or that a Collection (or array) is not empty (not null and length > 0)

Maybe you're looking for something else? Like [`NotNull`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html), or [`Min`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html)?

Comment: Thanks, ill check that soon and let u know if NotNull will give proper results :)

Comment: Its ok now. Thanks for your help, i should check api manual before asking stupid questions like this :)